# Difference between find ~ and find *

Tags: shell, find, filenames, wildcards

What is the difference between  `find *` and `find ~` for searching a file?
In terminal when my present working directory on `root`,then in terminal

```
root@devils-ey3:~# find * -print -quit
~
```

On same directory

```
root@devils-ey3:~# find ~ -print -quit
/root
```

But if I change the `pwd` then the output of `find ~ -print -quit` is same as before but the other is change.
What is the working purpose of `*` and `~` for find file ?

Comment: Do you have a file (or directory) named `~` in your `/root` directory?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The basic format of `find` is

```
find WHERE WHAT
```

So, in `find *`, the `*` is taken as the `WHERE`. Now, `*` is a wildcard. It matches everything in the current directory (except, by default, files/directories starting with a `.`). The Windows equivalent is `*.*`. This means that `*` is *expanded* to all files and directories in your current directory before it is passed to `find`. To illustrate, consider this directory:

```
$ ls
file  file2
```

If we run `set -x` to enable debugging info and then run your `find` command, we see:

```
$ find * -print -quit
+ find file file2 -print -quit
file
```

As you can see above, the `*` is expanded to all files in the directory and what is actually run is

```
find file file2 -print -quit
```

Because of `-quit`, this prints the first file name of the ones you told it to look for and exits. In your case, you seem to have a file or directory called `~` so that is the one that is printed.

The tilde (`~`), however, also has a special meaning. It is a shortcut to your `$HOME` directory:

```
$ echo ~
/home/terdon
```

So, when you run `find ~`, as root, the `~` is expanded to `/home/root` and the command you run is actually:

```
# find ~ -print -quit
+ find /root -print -quit
/root
```

Again, you are telling `find` to search for files or directories in a specific location and exit after printing the first one. Since the first file or directory matching `/root` is itself, that's what is printed.

Answer (score 0):

First of all kept in mind the syntax of `find`:-

```
find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-D debugopts] [-Olevel] [path...] [expression]
```

> What is the difference between find * and find ~ for searching a file?

- `*` is while card which matches everything.

  Here `find *` passes the list of files/dirs in the current directory and those as target names to search for. so, it will find all files with the same name as the ones in `pwd`

  <sup>(thanks to [@terdon](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22222/terdon) for [explaining](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/22231294#22231294) what 'find *' does ; see [that](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/209989/66803) answer)</sup>
- [`~`](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Tilde#Directories_and_URLs) used for [`$HOME`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_directory) Directory.

  So, `find ~` finds for files and directory (recursively) within `~` (home directory)

---

> ```
> root@devils-ey3:~# find * -print -quit
> ~
> ```

There must be file or directory named `~` inside `/root` which case above output. (*not confuse with `~` as `$HOME` directory*)

---

> ```
> root@devils-ey3:~# find ~ -print -quit
> /root
> ```

**Explanation for `find ~ -print -quit`:-**

Considerable option: `-quit`:

```
-quit  Exit  immediately.  No child processes will be left running, but no more paths specified on the command
              line will be processed.  For example, find /tmp/foo /tmp/bar -print -quit  will  print  only  /tmp/foo.
              Any  command  lines  which have been built up with -execdir ... {} + will be invoked before find exits.
              The exit status may or may not be zero, depending on whether an error has already occurred.
```

1. `~` is taken as path i.e. `/root` because you are on rooted terminal.
2. `-quit` prints directory name only

> But if I change the pwd then the output of find ~ -print -quit is same as before...

As explained above:- **`find ~ -print -quit`** prints **`/root`** every-time  as path is set to `~` (which is `/root` because of rooted shell) and used `-quite`. (independent of `pwd`!)